# How can I create two endpoints to access nuxt.js for frontend and Wordpress for backend inside of Docker container?

Tags: wordpress, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, nuxt.js

I am using a specialized repo from GitHub called Wuxt by Northosts that uses Nuxt.js v2 in the frontend and Wordpress in the backend as a headless CMS and works exclusively inside of a Docker container. I am able to locally access the frontend for Nuxt.js and the backend Dashboard and API for Wordpress. The documentation provides local base url endpoints `http://localhost:3000` for the frontend and `http://localhost:3080` & `http://localhost:3080/wp-admin` for the backend dashboard and Wordpress API. However, the framework doesn't provide documentation / direction or doesn't seem to generate new base url endpoints that would be used for production deployments on both sides.

I was wondering if there is a way inside of Docker to generate all of those base url endpoints for both the frontend and backend that could potentially be used to be routed by DNS. (routing the frontend to the main domain and the backend & api to their own sub-domains).

I am still somewhat of a newbie when it comes to Docker, so I apologize in advance for any misunderstandings in potential questions you may ask me about my Docker configuration, but will still try to answer them as best as I can.

I am using docker-compose to configure my Docker container. I have tried (from what I understand) to generate static ipv4 addresses for all of my containers and use those for base url endpoints. I have tried deploying to an AWS EC2 container and accessing those custom ipv4 urls to no results. Also have tried accessing the public ipv4 address that was given to me by my AWS EC2 instance and adding the exposed port numbers that I assigned to each image in my container to the end of the public EC2 ipv4 address. Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file below.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    mysql.wuxt:
        container_name: ${WUXT_MYSQL_CONTAINER:-mysql.wuxt}
        image: mysql:8.1.0
        volumes:
            - ./_db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: wuxt-website
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dev
        networks:
          - default
        deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 160M
            reservations:
              memory: 128M
        memswap_limit: 5G

    wp.wuxt:
        container_name: ${WUXT_WP_CONTAINER:-wp.wuxt}
        image: wordpress:6.3.2-php8.2-apache
        volumes:
          - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw,cached
        expose:
          - '${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}'
        ports:
          - '${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}:80'
        environment:
          WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${WUXT_MYSQL_CONTAINER:-mysql.wuxt}:3306
          WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wuxt-website
          WORDPRESS_DB_USER: root
          WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: dev
          WUXT_PORT_BACKEND: ${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}
          WORDPRESS_CONFIG_EXTRA: |
            define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost:${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}' );
            define('WP_HOME', 'http://localhost:${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}' );
        hostname: hostwp
        networks:
          backend:
            ipv4_address: "192.168.80.6"

    front.wuxt:
        container_name: ${WUXT_NUXT_CONTAINER:-front.wuxt}
        image: node:18.18.2-slim
        working_dir: '/var/www/app'
        environment:
            - HOST=0.0.0.0
            - WUXT_WP_CONTAINER=${WUXT_WP_CONTAINER:-wp.wuxt}
            - WUXT_PORT_BACKEND=${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080}
        ports:
            - '${WUXT_PORT_FRONTEND-3000}:3000'
        volumes:
            - ./nuxt:/var/www/app
        command: bash -c "yarn install && WUXT_PORT_BACKEND=${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080} yarn start"
        # command: bash -c "yarn install && WUXT_PORT_BACKEND=${WUXT_PORT_BACKEND:-3080} yarn dev"
        hostname: hostnode
        networks:
          frontend:
            ipv4_address: "10.10.0.1"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.0.0/16
          gateway: 192.168.0.1
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.10.0.0/16
          gateway: 10.10.0.1
```